# Disable search button

Tags: iphone, xcode, search, button, dictionary

I have a problem and would appreciate it if you would help me.

I made a app from this tutorial:

http://www.lonhosford.com/lonblog/2011/05/08/xcode-4-iphone-tutorial-mountains-of-the-usa-overview/?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150196924999637_19584378_10150363736289637#f20e4d75c4

It works great, but i need it without the search button. I want to see all the data when i start the app... without taping on the search button or anything else.

I am in the learning process and it would help me a lot if someone would answer.

On the link you will find all the codes i used in the app.

Thanks a lot!!

David R.

Comment: there is no code in that link

Answer (score 3):

remove the button from the interface and just call the method associated with the tap of the button from your viewDidLoad.